# Two different table name in Codeigniter update function

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

**Basic Information**
Codeigniter: 3, PHP 5

I am currently playing with a multiple table update at one update query. My SQL as follows-

```
UPDATE users as a, u_basicinfos as b
SET 
    a.first_name = 'XYI',
    b.Address = 'USA',
    b.PortalURL = NULL
WHERE a.id = b.UserId AND b.InfosId = 1
```

Above query absolutely works fine with `heidisql` or `phpmyadmin` sql console.

I am trying to create a `active records` query in codeigniter as follows-

```
$this->db->where('a.id = b.UserId');
$this->db->where('b.Infosid', $infoid);

$tblname = 'users AS a, u_basicinfos AS b';
// may be problem with this format of two tables name

$query = $this->db->update($tblname, $data);
```

**As a note: *I have assigned `$data` array in Controller:***

```
$data = array (
    'a.first_name' => $this->input->post('first_name'),
    'b.Address' => $this->input->post('Address'),
    'b.NewportalURL' => $this->input->post('PortalURL')
);
```

Now, I am struggling with following errors.

```
Table 'finalportal.users as a, u_basicinfos' doesn't exist

UPDATE `users AS a, u_basicinfos` AS `b` SET `a`.`first_name` = 'XYI',
`b`.`Address` = 'USA', `b`.`PortalURL` = NULL
```

I need some idea on this. Let me know what I am doing wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try using this in query

```
$this->db->where('b.Infosid', $infoid);
$tblname = 'users a JOIN u_basicinfos b on a.id = b.UserId';
$query = $this->db->update($tblname, $data);
```

Comment: Tried. No Luck. I think problem with the `tables name` in the update function first parameter. It would be in proper way. I am something doing wrong here, absolutely.